# data structure sort + search effective

Tags: search, sorting, tree

I need to have a data structure with say 4 keys and other data; and i can sort on any of these keys. what data structure can i opt for ?
sorting time should be very less

thought of a tree but will be only help searching on one key . ... for other keys will have to remake the tree on that particular key and then find it...
any data structure that can have which will take care of all 4 keys at  same time?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: For more generic questions like this, it might be better to ask at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is no such structure that will guarantee you the same access time to each value.

The most effective structures for searching are `trees`. There are lots of different kinds of trees. The most simple is the `binary search tree`. But the possibility that you will have to iterate through all keys still existing in this structure.

That's why I recommend you the balanced version of this tree. Binary trees are simple structures.

If you are looking for something more advanced, check out the `B-Tree`. This structure is used by database indexes and are considered very effective and quick.

Comment: thanks Dave.. any idea how does database sort for different keys as we can sort on different keys ?

Comment: Can you please provide an example? The way database do sorting depends on many factors. The most efficient way is to choose keys that match your searching criteria, sort them, and later use them only as a reference to obtain the data.

Comment: my four fields are : source ip , destination ip, source port  and destination port..

Comment: If I needed to search for source IPs, I would create one index and use source IP as the key. If you need to search for both - source IP and destination IP, you will need two search indexes. If your query is more complicated. e.g. select source IP that match criteria A and then match destination IP with criteria B, you will need so called compound index. This index combines two indexes into one. Anyway, you can always have each index for one key and iterate over the resulting array of records, remove records that does not match further criteria and after that sort it.